# Docker compose version 2 volumes not using specified location

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I cannot figure out version 2 of docker compose.
Everything was working nicely with version 1, but it now seems to be ignoring the volumes_from for the database, whenever I start it up, after rebuilding, the db already has a database in it from a different container, not running, so it isn't using the volumes location specified in sql-data below?

```
version: '2'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_apache_1"
        build: ./images/apache/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes_from:
            - application

    php-fpm:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_phpfpm_1"
        build: ./images/php-fpm-7.0/
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes_from:
            - application

    sql-server:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_sql_1"
        image: mariadb:10.1
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 
            MYSQL_USER: 
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
        volumes_from:
            - sql-data
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        expose:
            - 3306

    sql-data:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_sqldata_1"
        image: mariadb:10.1
        volumes:
            - ./database/fix:/var/lib/mysql/data

    application:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_app_1"
        image: php:7.0-fpm
        volumes:
            - ../www:/var/www/html
            - ./images/app/fix-settings.inc.php:/var/www/html/config/settings.inc.php
        command: "true"

    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: "quotationspro_fix_phpmyadmin_1"
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: "sql-server"
            PMA_POST: "3306"
```

Comment: Check out logs of docker try ```docker logs id_container```

Comment: looking for what?  Everything starts up correctly, it's just that it seems to be using a database volume from somewhere else, not from here: volumes:
            - ./database/fix:/var/lib/mysql/data